# Oracle GRoup by 7 Days

Tags: oracle, date, group-by

I'm trying to group seven days period for each date, but this seems not to work.

```
 select 
 START_DATE-7 FROM_DATES,
 SUM(EVENT_B),
 SUM(EVENT_B)  
  FROM (
  select 
  nvl(ENT1.DATE_FIELD,ENT2.DATE_FIELD)as START_DATE,
  nvl(ENT1.EVENT_A,0) as EVENT_A,
  nvl(ENT2.EVENT_B,0) as EVENT_B
  from 
 (select 
  DATE_FIELD, SUM(NR_EVENTS) as EVENT_A
  from TABLE_A
  where  EVENT_NAME in ('CALL',  'EDIT','INSERT') 
  group by START_DATE,START_HOUR,SUBSCRIBER_TYPE,CO_ID
) ENT1 
 FULL OUTER JOIN
(select 
 DATE_FIELD,
 SUM(NR_EVENTS) as EVENT_B
 from TABLE_B
 where  EVENT_NAME in ('CALL',  'EDIT','INSERT') 
 group by DATE_FIELD
) ENT2 
on ( 
ENT1.DATE_FIELD=ENT2.DATE_FIELD)
)
WHERE 
START_DATE >= START_DATE-7
AND START_DATE <= START_DATE-1
gROUP BY 
START_DATE-7
```

The output im getting:

```
9/8/2014    262187  280365
9/7/2014    509405  478245
9/6/2014    564663  537996
9/5/2014    661871  632689
9/4/2014    669788  638839
```

Its only sum for one day not 7

The output should be

`2014-09-15`, (sum of event from A side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-15`-7 to `2014-09-15`) , (sum of event from B side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-15`-7 to `2014-09-15`)
`2014-09-14`, (sum of event from A side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-14`-7 to `2014-09-14`) , (sum of event from B side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-14`-7 to `2014-09-14`)
`2014-09-13`, (sum of event from A side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-13`-7 to `2014-09-13`) , (sum of event from B side in a 7 days period - `2014-09-13`-7 to `2014-09-13`)

etc...

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please provide some sample of data from both tables with the current output of your query and some expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with event_dates as (
  select d_field from table_a
  union
  select d_field from table_b
)
select
  d_field from_date,
  d_field to_date,
  (
    select nvl(sum(nr_events),0) from table_a
    where event_name in ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT')
    and d_field between e.d_field and e.d_field+6
  ) nr_events_a,
  (
    select nvl(sum(nr_events),0) from table_b
    where event_name in ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT')
    and d_field between e.d_field and e.d_field+6
  ) nr_events_b
from event_dates e;
```

I made [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62ee4/6/0) based on your original post and notes from [Lalit Kumar B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25843696/2495654). Answer above includes `event_name` field filter which was later added.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect.

Firstly, your output doesn't match with the selected columns. If 1st column is `D_FIELD1+7`, then how is that in the output the first column values are `D_FIELD1`?

Secondly, the predicate `AND D_FIELD1 BETWEEN D_FIELD1+7 AND D_FIELD1` is ambiguous.

Thirdly, `BETWEEN` will include the upper and lower bound, so you will get the window of 8 days and not 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Analytic function with an Interval e.g.

```
SELECT nvl(ent1.date_field, ent2.date_field) - 6 start_date
     , nvl(ent1.date_field, ent2.date_field) end_date
     , sum(event_a) OVER
         (ORDER BY nvl(ent1.date_field, ent2.date_field)
          RANGE numtodsinterval(6, 'day') PRECEDING
         ) sum_event_a
     , sum(event_b) OVER
         (ORDER BY nvl(ent1.date_field, ent2.date_field)
          RANGE numtodsinterval(6, 'day') PRECEDING
         ) sum_event_b
FROM (SELECT date_field,
             sum(nr_events) AS event_a
      FROM table_a
      WHERE event_name IN ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT') 
      GROUP BY date_field
     ) ent1 
     FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT date_field,
             sum(nr_events) AS event_b
      FROM table_b
      WHERE event_name IN ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT') 
      GROUP BY date_field
     ) ent2
       ON (ent1.date_field = ent2.date_field)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the way of get the sums, I prefer in this case analytic functions. Try something like this:

```
SELECT START_DATE - 7 FROM_DATES,
       SUM (EVENT_A) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE RANGE 7 PRECEDING),
       SUM (EVENT_B) OVER (ORDER BY START_DATE RANGE 7 PRECEDING)
  FROM (SELECT NVL (ENT1.DATE_FIELD, ENT2.DATE_FIELD) AS START_DATE,
               NVL (ENT1.EVENT_A, 0) AS EVENT_A,
               NVL (ENT2.EVENT_B, 0) AS EVENT_B
          FROM    (  SELECT DATE_FIELD, SUM (NR_EVENTS) AS EVENT_A
                       FROM TABLE_A
                      WHERE EVENT_NAME IN ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT')
                   GROUP BY START_DATE,
                            START_HOUR,
                            SUBSCRIBER_TYPE,
                            CO_ID) ENT1
               FULL OUTER JOIN
                  (  SELECT DATE_FIELD, SUM (NR_EVENTS) AS EVENT_B
                       FROM TABLE_B
                      WHERE EVENT_NAME IN ('CALL', 'EDIT', 'INSERT')
                   GROUP BY DATE_FIELD) ENT2
               ON (ENT1.DATE_FIELD = ENT2.DATE_FIELD))
```